# meaning of "with two-thirds of the voting rights, and a third of outstanding shares"

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context

> The merger plan must win approval from shareholders **with two-thirds of
>   the voting rights, and a third of outstanding shares** in order to pass
>   a shareholder meeting scheduled for July 17.

I quoted the above sentence from the article about the M&A of Samsung C&T.

I'm not sure about the meaning of **"with two-thirds of the voting rights, and a third of outstanding shares"**.

Does this mean that the approval requires share holders whose shares add up to more than one third of total shares to participate in the vote and two thirds of voters to agree with M&A?

Comment: I'm only familiar with British company law.  I can understand *two-thirds of the voting rights*. There may be different classes of shares with differing voting rights. **But I don't understand what is meant by *outstanding shares***.

Comment: I have looked this up and it appears to mean 'all the shares held by the company shareholders', what in the UK we would call *issued shares*. So if you have different categories of shares with different voting rights, I think the meaning of the expression becomes evident. But remember this is an English Language site, and you should take the advice of a lawyer before placing any reliance on what I have just said.

Comment: Some shares are given more votes than others -- it's not "one share, one vote".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outstanding shares are all the shares that were issued by the company.

It is possible to assign special voting rights to certain shares (or even have shares with *no* voting rights at all!)

So if a company issues 200 special shares which entitle you to 10 votes each, and 1000 normal shares that give you one vote each, we have a total of 3000 possible votes and 1200 outstanding shares.

In this case for the proposal to be accepted, there should be 1000 *votes* for the proposal, and holders of at least 400 *shares* (of any kind) should be for it.

Which means that if only the holders of the special shares would vote for the proposal, it would not be accepted, since that would be 2000 votes, but only 1/6 of the shares. Likewise, if only the holders of normal shares vote for the proposal, that represents 5/6 of the shares, but only 1/3 of the vote.